# html5 structure when the h1 is an img background

Tags: html, tags

I have a very simple page (perhaps too simple) I just have a title and a text. I want to apply the new html5 semantic elements. The first problem is with the title. For design reasons I want it to be an img and I use a img background. So I do not use an h1. This does not create the correct outline of the page. How do I do this page with correct semantic html5?

You can use this: http://jsfiddle.net/Narcis/ktF96/

CSS:

```
#title{
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-image:url('img.png');
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="title"></div>

<div id="text">
  <p>text, text,</p>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, you can save on JSFiddle, which is much more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a background image as your H1, use `text-indent` to hide the H1 text from sighted users (but not from screen-reader users or search engines) and specify the path to the background image and its height.

For example, your HTML would be something like this:

```
<h1>Art of the Title</h1>
```

And the CSS:

```
h1 {
    text-indent: -999em; // that's the most you can left indent something
    background: url('/PATH/TO/YOUR/IMG.png'); // your background image
    height: 300px; // the height of your background image
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ktF96/1/)